# Using font awesome as cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I want to change the cursor icon while waiting using the following code I found here:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 110;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.font = "20px FontAwesome";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillText("\uf245", 35, 25);
ctx.font = "35px FontAwesome";
ctx.fillText("\uf013", 55, 15);

var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
$('body').css('cursor', 'url(' + dataURL + '), auto');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Does anyone know if I can make the gear rotating?

Comment: I believe the only way to do something animated as cursor is to put cursor as none and replace it with your custom element via js tracking mouse position

Comment: you are right! I didn't searched for animated cursor. that's why I didn't find it. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS `cursor:wait`. This uses the user's own cursor settings, which is what you should use because this helps users understand much more easily that the process is running. Consistency is very important.

```css
html,body {height:100%}
body {cursor:wait}
```

Seems good to me.